# Programa Java só funciona na máquina de desenvolvimento

Tags: java, netbeans, deploy, jar

Eu criei uma aplicação Java no NetBeans. Essa aplicação tem uma GUI e usa alguns Jars externos.

Após fazer o Clean and Build na pasta dist do NetBeans apareceu um Jar (main class) e uma pasta chamada lib (que tem os Jars externos que uso). Ao executar o Jar (main class) que está na pasta dist tudo funciona normalmente. Verifiquei o Class-Path e está tudo OK. Inclusive mudei o nome da pasta onde estão as libs e o programa deixou de dar, o que significa que os Jars da pasta lib estão a ser usados e não outros.

O problema é que ao copiar a pasta dist (que tem a main class e os Jars externos) para outro computador (com a mesma versão do Java instalado) o programa não funciona.

Alguém consegue ajudar-me?

Comment: Está faltando algum jar. Para saber qual é sugiro que você invoque o seu jar executável pelo cmd, assim será possível ver qual exceção está sendo lançada, pois quando dá dois cliques você não tem feedback nenhum, correto?

Comment: Se as dependências estão num subdiretório, isso significa que ao executar o Jar esse diretório deve estar sendo informado de alguma forma para a JVM. Qual o classpath que vc verificou? Se for o do netbeans, ele não vai ser o mesmo quando o jar for executado fora desse ambiente. Ou talvez ele esteja configurado com caminho absoluto ao invés de relativo. Seria interessante postar mais informações sobre a sua configuração.

Comment: Alguma mensagem de erro? O que é "o programa não funciona"?

Comment: @Math Um dos Jars usava um ficheiro auxiliar que estava em falta...ao ver na consola percebi qual era o ficheiro. Obrigado.

Comment: @utluiz O class path que veriquei foi o do main jar

Comment: @Caffé o programa ao arrancar usava um dos jars auxiliares (lib) e este usava um ficheiro auxiliar que não estava presente.

Comment: @JoãoFonseca Então já resolveu o problema?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando não acontece nada ao tentar abrir o programa, é por que ele lançou uma exceção antes mesmo de carregar a parte gráfica, logo não é mostrado nenhum erro para o usuário.

Para conseguir ver qual é a exceção que está sendo lançada você pode executar seu jar através do prompt de comando ou terminal, pois ele lançará a exceção que está ocorrendo e então você conseguirá a explicação do seu problema, assim ficará fácil arrumar seu projeto.

Para invocá-lo através de linha de comando use o seguinte comando:

```
java -jar nomedojar.jar
```

No seu caso, é muito provável que está faltando alguma dependência, pois o programa funciona corretamente no seu computador e aparentemente a configuração do outro está ok, pelo que você disse. Com a dica da exceção no prompt, adicione o jar que estiver faltando ao seu projeto.

Comment: Apeoveitando que levantaram a questão: [Por que muitas pessoas respondem nos comentarios em vez de criar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2333/3117)